# Why is TextInputLayout taking so much time in drawing?

Tags: android, performance, android-textinputlayout

I have a simple form made using the Material Design's `TextInputLayout`. The form is displayed by a separate Fragment with ConstraintLayout as its root. When I navigate from *HomeFragment* to *FormFragment*, the layout takes half a second to display.

And, as I am using the Navigation component, the toolbar gets updated first and then after half second, the form layout loads.

On running **Systrace**, I found that rendering that frame took about 267ms. Most of the time was spent in Measure/Layout pass.